# how to define any element in step size in XML schema

Tags: xsd

if i want to define any element in XML schema like min value is 0 and max value is 91800 in step 360 means possible combination are 0,360,720 and so on without using enumeration pattern

how i can define this?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot think of any way to do it - you cannot do arithmetic in validation rules.

You're stuck with using enumeration (that in your case seems possible - it is 256 possible values if I am not mistaken).

Answer (score 0):

Since a finite state automaton can recognize the set of numbers evenly divisible by 360, it's possible in principle to do this with a fiendishly complicated regular expression, but for the range you have in mind an enumeration would in fact be a lot easier to understand (and to write correctly).

So in XSD 1.0, it's not quite true that using an enumeration is the only way to define the type you want, but it is true that it's by far the simplest and best way.

In XSD 1.1, you can use an assertion expressed in XPath 2.0 to capture the arithmetic relation:

```
<xs:simpleType name="small-multiples-of-three-sixty">
  <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
    <xs:minInclusive value="0"/>
    <xs:maxInclusive value="91800"/>
    <xs:assertion test="$value mod 360 eq 0"/>
  </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```